# Bash variable assignment not working expected

Tags: linux, bash

```
status=0
$status=1

echo $status
```

Can anyone tell my what i am doing wrong with this?

It gives me the following error:

```
 0=1: command not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is OK - it assigns the value 0 to the variable `status`:

```
status=0
```

This is wrong:

```
$status=1
```

By putting a `$` in front of the variable name you are dereferencing it, i.e. getting its value, which in this case is `0`.  In other words, `bash` is expanding what you wrote to:

```
0=1
```

Which makes no sense, hence the error.

If your intent is to reassign a new value `1` to the status variable, then just do it the same as the original assignment:

```
status=1
```

Comment: `0=1` makes perfect sense syntactically, but it will not do what the user intended. If an executable file named `0=1` exists in the user's path, it will be run.

Comment: @chepner - yes, very true.

Answer (score 1):

Bash assignments can't have a dollar in front. Variable replacements in bash are like macro expansions in C; they occur before any parsing. For example, this horrible thing works:

```
foof="[ -f"
if $foof .bashrc ] ; then echo "hey"; fi
```

Comment: Not quite that hairy; parsing is done first, but `[` is not syntax (it's a command name), so it works as expected. `foo=if; $foo [ -f .bashrc ]; then echo "hey"; fi` would properly fail with a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Only use the `$` when actually using the variable in bash. Omit it when assigning or re-assining.

e.g.

```
status=0
status2=1
status="$status2"
```

Answer (score 0):

also this ugly thing works too :

```
status='a'
eval $status=1

echo $a 
1
```

Comment: Or you can achieve extra levels of indirection using a parameter expansion like this: `a=1; status='a'; echo ${!status}`